# Reveal elements on hover and element alignment in header with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, header, alignment

I have a full width sticky header located at the top of my pages. On this header, a logo is located at the left, a navigation menu in the middle and a search icon at the extreme right.

I am looking to make a popup appear when hovering over the search icon with my mouse. I want the popup to stay visible for as long as the mouse pointer is located inside the popup or over the search icon.

I would also like to have the extreme right of my popup window at the extreme  right of my small search icon.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="container_header clearfix">

            <div class="menu-row-top clearfix">

            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
                    <img src="/small_logo.png" alt="logo" height="44" width="210">
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <nav class="primary">
                  <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'container'       => 'ul', 
                    'menu_class'      => 'sf-menu', 
                    'menu_id'         => 'topnav',
                    'depth'           => 0,
                    'theme_location' => 'header_menu' 
                    )); 
                  ?>
                </nav><!--.primary-->


            <div class="header-search">
                <a class="search"><img src="/search_icon.png" alt="search_icon" height="28" width="28"></a>
                    <div class="header-search-form">
                        This is the search form
                    </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.container_header{
background: #0459b5; 
}

.menu-row-top {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 960px;
   height:44px;
}

.header-logo{
float: left;
display:block;
}

nav.primary {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-search{
float:right;
display:block;
margin-top:7px;
margin-left: 12px;
}

.header-search-form{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 44px;
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #036dda;
    height: 80px;
}


a.search:hover + .header-search-form{
display: block;
}
```

With the above code, my popup window with the search form appears when my mouse hover the search icon but does not stay visible if I hover the search form. I would like to get the correct CSS markup to do so.

Furthermore, the popup is aligned from the left side of the search icon all the way to the right of my screen. I tried playing a bit with the position (left, right) but it seems to send the window all the way to the two extremes of my screen which are off the 960px width. I would also want the window to always stay at the same position no matter how I resize my browser's window (i.e. aligned from the right side of my search icon from right to left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get your pop-up working i edited these in your css http://jsfiddle.net/ce1j6k7k/3/

```
.header-search-form {
z-index:1000;
display:none;
position: fixed;
top: 44px;
background: green;
width: 400px;
border-bottom: solid 4px #036dda;
height: 80px;
}
.header-search:hover  .header-search-form {
display: block;
}
```

i gave a higher `z-index` value so that it will always be on top

Comment: For some reason, it will only works for the first time I hover the icon, then, it stops working properly when the mouse is over the popup. I have to reload the page to make it work again...

Comment: It works in the link you sent, but it doesn't on my website unfortunately. It would only work 1 time and then, I would have to refresh the page to make it work again!

Comment: It sends the popup window all the way to the right side of my screen, which is definitely not desired since it's way off the 960px width I'm looking to keep my stuff in. Basically, I want the extreme right of the popup window to be aligned with the extreme right of the small icon. With the code listed in my question, the left border of the popup window is aligned with the left side of my icon.

Comment: @LaGuille it is moving to the right but because of its width you can't see it try zooming out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64569/discussion-between-laguille-and-akshay).

Comment: @LaGuille i changed `right:0` to `  margin-left:-250px;` now it seems to stay where it is  http://jsfiddle.net/ce1j6k7k/5/

Comment: Works perfectly now! +1